# Scoped mass assignment and accepts_nested_attributes_for in Rails 3.1 not working?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, scope, mass-assignment, scoped-mass-assignment

Using Rails 3.1 RC4.

My User model has the following:

```
  has_many :emails, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :emails
```

My Email model has the following:

```
  belongs_to :user
  attr_accessible :email, :email_confirmation, :as => :admin
```

In Rails console:

```
User.first.update_attributes!({:artist_name => 'foo', :emails_attributes => {0 => {:email => 'foo@blah.com', :email_confirmation => 'foo@foo.com'}}}, :as => :admin)
```

I get:

```
WARNING: Can't mass-assign protected attributes: email, email_confirmation
```

In my Email model, if I remove `:as => :admin`. Everything works...

Should I be assigning some kind of scope to `accepts_nested_attributes_for`? Anyone know how this can be fixed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue and solution has been highlighted [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/1673).

In summary, an options hash must be passed.